# take screenshot then delete it in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

So basically what I want to do for a test is to take a screenshot, upload it on a website and then delete the said screenshot from the directory.
Is there a way to make the screenshot only temporary? 
I know how to take the screenshot, I use this method:

```
File scrShot = ((TakesScreenshot)webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

try 
{
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrShot, new File ("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\newscreen.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

So I want a way in the `@AfterClass`, after tests are finished to be able to delete the `newscreen.jpg`. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
try {
    Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\newscreen.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately i get this error :
_The method deleteIfExists(Path) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (String)._

Also, if I try to use a single backslash "\" I get the error _" Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"_ so I have to use the double backslash.

Comment: I've updated my answer, the above should now work, the argument for it needed to be a Path object.

Comment: Also, you should mark the answer as correct if it has worked for you so people looking in future can see.